# File upload Null reference application in asp.net VB.net

Tags: exception, reference, null

HI I get the following error in my application

System.NullReferenceException.Object Reference not set to an instance of an object on the code. I don't understand why it is throwing this particular exception.

```
   Dim namePosition As Int16
    Dim stream As IO.Stream

    stream = File1.PostedFile.InputStream
    Dim uploadedFile(stream.Length) As Byte

    stream.Read(uploadedFile, 0, stream.Length)

    namePosition = File1.PostedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1
    fileName = File1.PostedFile.FileName.Substring(namePosition)
    fileType = File1.PostedFile.ContentType
```

Comment: Which line is causing the null ref?

Comment: this particular problem is occurring in safari                       stream = File1.PostedFile.InputStream